# Add hint (like OnMouseMove) to Play, Pause and Stop buttons in flash player(player_mp3_maxi)

Tags: flash, button, mp3

I am using "http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/maxi/" flash player in my html page.
And there also have source code("https://github.com/neolao/mp3-player").

It works for me good.

But, i want to add hint (like OnMouseMove) to Play, Pause and Stop buttons.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hint for each button (I assume a text field with text). Make it invisible at start. In each button add code like:

```
on (rollOver) { 
      //show my hint; 
}

on (rollOut) { 
      //hide my hint
}
```

Another way would be to make a movieclip called hint_mc. Create 4 keyframes, Put stop() action in all of them. Leave the first frame blank. Create your hints on frame 2,3,4, one each. Then add code to your button like:

```
on (rollOver) { 
   hint_mc.goToAndPlay(framenummer); 
}

on (rollOut) { 
   hint_mc.goToAndPlay(0); 
}
```